# Update array values in parse(Heroku)

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to update array values in parse .Below is what I have done to achieve it

```
for (int i=0;i<wishList.size();i++){
                        if (online2_g_s.getObjectId().equals(wishList.get(i))){
                            wishList.remove(i);

                        }
                    }
                    Log.i("sand",wishList.toString());
                    user.addAllUnique("wishList", Arrays.asList(wishList));
                    user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Item removed your WishList", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

where wishlist is my  list from which i have to delete and update its items.
Before running this piece of code wishlist was: ***["none","sandeep","3sIgT00P5O","6P5K609tpW","G5RmQ0S3kB"]***

And after running this piece of code whishlist is:

**["none","sandeep","3sIgT00P5O","6P5K609tpW","G5RmQ0S3kB",["none","sandeep","3sIgT00P5O","6P5K609tpW"]]**  *G5RmQ0S3kB was removed*

what i am trying to achieve is **["none","sandeep","3sIgT00P5O","6P5K609tpW"]**

Comment: side note - you're modifying `wishList` while iterating on it - if more than 1 item matches you may skip items this way.

Comment: will you please elaborate.Thank you

Comment: You remove items from `wishList` inside a for loop. Try setting `wishList` to contain `["a", "a", "a", "a"]` 4 times, and run the loop testing for `"a".equals(wishList.get(i))`. You'd expect `wishList` to be empty, but it won't be.

Comment: Thank you  i got it